# Resources of realistic water simulation?

Tags: 3d, physics, simulations

I want to study water simulation, with a  a demo with source code which using physically-based methods(Eulerian approaches or Lagrangian approaches).

How can I get some examples?

Answer (score 10):

Here is one, with source

[Fluid simulation for video games series : Part 1 - 9](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fluid-simulation-for-video-games-part-1/)

Answer (score 4):

Q-Games [presented](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7q8s7DMOOD4) their system for Pixeljunk Shooter at SIGGRAPH:

Disclaimer: I got this information from [another StackOverflow post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17701/how-does-pixeljunk-shooter-simulate-its-liquids).

I've also seen those slides in PDF/Powerpoint form, but don't know where they are at the moment. All of the information is available in the Youtube videos, however.