# How does pixeljunk shooter simulate its liquids?

Tags: physics, rendering, simulations, particles

I am really impressed by the liquids in [pixeljunk shooter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9piUeupkQs). I would love to know how they do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an excellent SIGGRAPH presentation on PixelJunk Shooter 2's lighting and physics simulation, including fluid mechanics, [available on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7q8s7DMOOD4).